# Export Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey in simple text/readable format

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, journey

We have multiple journeys (some simple some complicated) created in Marketing Cloud. Do we have any way to get/download the journey (flowchart) in some readable (like XML or Json) format.

The issue is our POs need to go through the journey and every now and then they have difficulty going over the all 20 splits and changes we made in journey. They want to see it in more readable format for business..

Comment: You might have more luck asking at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ Questions not related to code are poor fit for StackOverflow, on the other hand admins and MC specialists frequent that sister site

Comment: Thanks, I will post it there and add link here.